# Does this sentence sound natural: "Personne ne me ressemble pas sauf junior."?

Tags: grammaire, sens, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

I put *"à"* because I am referring to myself.

What should I do, please?

Translation of the sentence: I do not resemble anybody except junior.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by putting à... it would be helpful if you would include both versions of the sentence that you are comparing in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Not only does it not sound natural, but it's not correct and I don't understand what you mean. Could you add the English version of what you meant?

Comment: Personne **ne** me ressemble, sauf Junior. Dans cette tournure de phrase, le *ne* inclus (ou sous-entend) le *…pas* suivant et la virgule est nécessaire.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not resemble anybody except junior.
>
> Je ne ressemble à personne sauf à junior

Is this what you meant? What you wrote in the title is more like

> Nobody looks like me except junior

but worth mentioning that as stated,

> Personne ne me ressemble **pas** sauf junior

it is incorrect owing to the redundant « pas ».

Comment: I'd add that *pas* is not needed in the phrase given in the OP.

Comment: Je ne ressemble à personne sauf ***à*** Junior.

Answer (score 1):

> *Personne ne me ressemble pas sauf junior.*

is very odd and, due to the double negative, literally means:

> Nobody doesn't look like me but junior.

which can be simplified to:

> Everyone look like me except junior.
> *Tout le monde me ressemble sauf junior.*

That's the opposite of your expected meaning:

> Personne ne me ressemble sauf junior.

Note also that naming someone (presumably your son) *junior* is also uncommon in France.